# Is RSS feed the way to go for NodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rss

I'm using Node.js and React to develop this simple web application for use within the company I work for, where users can register things such as outages and planned events. The idea is that the application will hold the data, and other components such as python script of java code elsewhere can forward this information into other software (chat rooms, emails, and so forth).

The current path I'm on is to implement a simple RSS feed into the application, that the external software (python script, java code, etc) can connect to in order to get updates from my web applications. So users will register events in my web application, which updates the RSS feed, and whoever (i.e. the external software) subscribes to the feed get instant updates.

My question is this: Is RSS the way to go to notify external software about events? I guess I could use Rabbit MQ or something, but I'm not sure which approach works best considering the homogeneous infrastructure it will be supporting.

Comments?